# Getting an exact solution using Solve

Tags: equation-solving, output

I run the command:

```
Solve[{Tan[x] == Coth[x], 1/2 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

And I get the following output:

> ```
> {{x -> Root[{
>     Coth[#] - Tan[#]& , 
>      0.93755203435598058322263302307754406772`20.30373238749785}]}}
> ```

How do I interpret this result from Solve? Furthermore, how do I get Mathematica to output this solution in closed form?  I know the numeric value is correct, but I don't want the numeric solution.

Comment: MMA version 13.1 Windows 10. I get a numerical value of: {x -> 0.937552}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Not every solution to an equation has a closed form. Is there any particular reason why you believe this equation has a closed form solution?

Comment: since the equation is non-linear, and if Mathematica can't find explicit exact solution, it will return Root object. **The Root object is an exact numeric expression**  not all non-linear equations can be solved explicitly.

Comment: `eqn = {Tan[x] == Coth[x], 1/2 <= x <= 1}; sol = 
 Solve[eqn, x]; eqn /. sol` shows that `sol` is exact.